# Backdoors and hard-coded usernames and passwords

Tags: windows, webserver, backdoor

I have been researching on computer worms that brought me to this topic of backdoors. According to my research, backdoors are malicious pieces of code that are inserted into either computers to get remote access to the target. I also learnt that usernames and passwords can be hard-coded into the program but I do not get what it means to hard-code and how it is done when writing the code for a backdoor.

Please refer me to sites that show examples of backdoors and how they work. It is mainly for informational purposes and as mentioned earlier in my previous question, I am doing a research for school: "What languages are backdoors written in and how they work."

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hard_coding

Comment: Backdoors can be written in any language... have you done any research on this before coming here?

Comment: yes, i did research, the most common languages i was referred to were c/c++

Comment: Stack Exchange is not a place to out source your homework.. "please refer me to sites that show examples of backdoors and how they work" It's okay to ask about theory, etc. but you should then be able to go out and discover and explore.

Answer (score 3):

Hard coded means that there is a piece of code like this (psuedocode)

```
$passwordInput = hash( getInputFromUser() ); //user provides password at logon
$usersPassWordHash = getUsersHashFromDB();   //lookup the user's password in the DB or other password storage
$secretPassword = hash("mybackdoor");        //Hash the hard-coded password

if($passwordInput == $usersPassWordHash OR $passwordInput == $secretPassword){
    //activity for verified user
}
```

Hard coded means the value is defined in the source code and is not subject to be changed at run time. In the example above `$secretPassword` is not set by the user, but is already there by the developer.

If there is a backdoor with a hard coded password, this means that anyone can type in the `$secretPassword` and gain access. Backdoors can also exist without password, for example there may be a secret URL that is not documented and skips the logon process altogether.

A popular example was from the [D-Link Router's backdoor](https://www.schneier.com/blog/archives/2013/10/d-link_router_b.html). The problem is clearly that once the backdoor is known (it is only protected by "security through obscurity") anyone can gain access using the backdoor - which means your authentication/logon doesn't even matter.